# No Endpoint Listening

Tags: wcf, web-services

Get the error message "There was no endpoint listening at http://subdomain.domain.com, This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException"

Any suggestions?

Comment: InnerException gives "System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved"

Comment: So this means: either your remote name is invalid, or you're behind a firewall blocking access to that remote site, or you need to be connecting using a VPN or something.... or your server doesn't handle name resolution (at all or not well)

Comment: My magic eight ball says: Did you make a change to your WCF service, and then forget to regenerate the service reference for your client application? Without more detail that's the best I've got.

Comment: @marc_s - you are WCF expert )

Answer (score 1):

answered by marc_s in the comments.  the problem was that the server wasn't handling the name resolution.  thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Check the configuration on the server and make sure your client's endpoint matches the server's endpoint.  Then make sure you're using the same binding as well, while you're at it.

After that, make sure the server is listening and the server's firewall isn't blocking you.

Thats all I've gotten from this Ouija board.  Anybody got a magic 8 ball?

Comment: I've checked the endpoints & bindings on both the server and client and both are the same.

I can successfully hit the service via web browser and firewall isn't blocking.  I'm about out of ideas on this one!